# create folder and files, timestamp them

Tags: python

Python Learner here. I am trying to evolve a script so that it creates a folder and names it with date/time etc... This part I have been able to do.

I want the resulting output of the script to be named per our standard, which I was also able to do.

Now I want to combine these actions so that when the script runs both actions happen together. Folder and files names and time stamped. But it is not working for me. Here are the errors python is giving me....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pan-backup-all.py", line 55, in <module>
    writeBackup(config, firewall["fwname"], folder)
  File "pan-backup-all.py", line 34, in writeBackup
    filename = "%s/%s.xml" % (folder, fwname, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('PaloAlto_%Y%m%d_%H%M'))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Here is the code with line numbers so the error codes have some context

https://app.box.com/s/dgo6nczegu5qdqijn8d7lbfsfr0ktfa2

I would of posted an imagine but my rep isnt high enough yet, silly.

Comment: You've shown *where* the error is, but not *what* it is, nor any of the code leading up to it.

Comment: @ScottHunter was having trouble posting the code so I went with a link so the line numbers in the error output has context, you should see it now. Thanks for looking.

Comment: You still haven't identified what the errors are.

Comment: I cleaned up the original post hopefully its more legible now

Answer (score 2):

`"%s/%s.xml"` expects 2 strings to fill the format string from; you supplied 3.

As it sounds like you want timestamp added to both folder & file names, which could be done like so:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('PaloAlto_%Y%m%d_%H%M')
filename = "%s%s/%s%s.xml" % (folder, timestamp, fwname, timestamp)
```

Comment: I understand what you said, not though how to fix it, do i add another %s?

Comment: @Tsquared that depends entirely on how you want the output to look. You could also concatenate the last two or first two strings. Again, it depends on how you want the output to look.

Comment: @RandomDavis output to look? Well, I am looking to see the script create a folder that is time stamped and place the output files in that folder also time stamped. Does that clarify what the output should look like?

Comment: @Tsquared Yes. In that case you'd simply concatenate the time string to the folder and file name strings, then pass those two strings as the format.

Comment: @RandomDavis can you show me how that might look, as I have not done it before. Thank you.

Comment: @Tsquared yeah instead of something like `"%s/%s.xml" % (folder, fwname, timestamp)`, you'd do `"%s/%s.xml" % (folder + timestamp, fwname + timestamp)`